# Why does this SAS code executing both the IF THEN DO and ELSE DO conditions?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
   *---------------------------------------*
   |  CREATING A GLOBAL VARIABLE GLOB      |
   *---------------------------------------*;
%GLOBAL GLOB;
   *---------------------------------------*
   |  CREATING A DATASET DST               |
   *---------------------------------------*;
DATA DST;
%LET GLOB = 1;

IF GLOB = 1 THEN DO
%LET GLOB =2;
%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
END;

ELSE DO;
%LET GLOB =3;
%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
END;

RUN;

%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
```

I am creating a global variable GLOB and within the Dataset DST, I am reassigning the value of GLOB to 1. So as per my understanding, it should only execute the "IF " condition. But in my case, both the "IF" and "else" conditions are getting executed. And if I am overwriting the value of GLOB as 2 in IF condition then why I am not getting value 2 for the last statement that is

**%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;**

Comment: Use CALL SYMPUTX() instead of %LET within a data step to create macros. You're basically mixing macro and data step logic and it doesn't work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't.  The macro pre-processor is evaluating the macro statments (%let etc.) before the data step is compiled and run.  So when the data step runs just the actual SAS statements (including any conditionally generate by the macro code) is what runs.

You are basically running this code:

```
%LET GLOB = 1;
%LET GLOB =2;
%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
%LET GLOB =3;
%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;

DATA DST;
  IF GLOB = 1 THEN DO;
  END;
  ELSE DO;
  END;
RUN;

%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
```

Note that your THEN clause will never run since your IF statement is testing the variable GLOB which can never be 1 since it has never been assigned any value. Only the **macro variable** named GLOB has been assigned any values.

Perhaps you meant to run something like this instead?

```
%LET GLOB = 1;

DATA DST;
  IF &GLOB = 1 THEN DO;
    call symputx('glob','2');
  END;
  ELSE DO;
    call symputx('glob','3');
  END;
RUN;

%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
```

Or something using macro code only? Like this:

```
%LET GLOB = 1;

%IF &GLOB = 1 %THEN %DO;
  %LET GLOB = 2;
%END;
%ELSE %DO;
  %LET GLOB = 3;
%END;

%PUT GLOB = &GLOB;
```